# Scientific notation android java

Tags: java, android, calculator

I've coded a simple calculator with java for android. I use double as my variables. The results it gives me are in scientific notation after it reaches a certain number of decimals although there is still is plenty of room for decimals. Is there any easy way I can convert scientific to "normal" notation?

I can now perform +,-,* and / with a button each. Input the two numbers to calculate in a edittext each. I output my result into another textfield.

For example:

If I multiply 25 by 1'000'000 I get 2.5E7
I'd like to get 25'000'000 as a result.

My code samples below:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.rechner;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void ButtonClickDurch (View view) {
    double zahl1;
    double zahl2;
    double Ergebnis;
    EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl1);
    EditText Feld2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl2);
    EditText FeldErgebnis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Ergebnis);
    if (Feld1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (Feld2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(Feld1.getText().toString());
    zahl2 = Double.parseDouble(Feld2.getText().toString());
    Ergebnis = zahl1 / zahl2;

    FeldErgebnis.setText(String.valueOf(Ergebnis));

}

public void ButtonClickPlus (View view) {
    double zahl1;
    double zahl2;
    double Ergebnis;
    EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl1);
    EditText Feld2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl2);
    EditText FeldErgebnis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Ergebnis);
    if (Feld1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (Feld2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(Feld1.getText().toString());
    zahl2 = Double.parseDouble(Feld2.getText().toString());
    Ergebnis = zahl1 + zahl2;

    FeldErgebnis.setText(String.valueOf(Ergebnis));

    }

public void ButtonClickMinus (View view) {
    double zahl1;
    double zahl2;
    double Ergebnis;
    EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl1);
    EditText Feld2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl2);
    EditText FeldErgebnis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Ergebnis);
    if (Feld1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (Feld2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(Feld1.getText().toString());
    zahl2 = Double.parseDouble(Feld2.getText().toString());
    Ergebnis = zahl1 - zahl2;

    FeldErgebnis.setText(String.valueOf(Ergebnis));
    }

public void ButtonClickMal (View view) {
    double zahl1;
    double zahl2;
    double Ergebnis;
    EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl1);
    EditText Feld2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl2);
    EditText FeldErgebnis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Ergebnis);
    if (Feld1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (Feld2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(Feld1.getText().toString());
    zahl2 = Double.parseDouble(Feld2.getText().toString());
    Ergebnis = zahl1 * zahl2;

    FeldErgebnis.setText(String.valueOf(Ergebnis));

}
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ABE033" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/Zahl1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zahl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zahl1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zahl1"
    android:text="@string/Zahl2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zahl2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Ergebnis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zahl2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zahl2"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10" />


 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonplus"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:onClick="ButtonClickPlus"
     android:text="@string/Plus"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Ergebnis"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>



 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttondurch"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
     android:onClick="ButtonClickDurch"
     android:text="@string/Durch"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonmal"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonmal"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Ergebnis"/>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonmal"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonminus"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonminus"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttondurch"
     android:onClick="ButtonClickMal"
     android:text="@string/Mal" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonminus"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonplus"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonplus"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonplus"
     android:onClick="ButtonClickMinus"
     android:text="@string/Minus" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Rechner</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="Zahl2">Zahl 2:</string>
<string name="Durch">:</string>
<string name="Zahl1">Zahl 1:</string>
<string name="Plus">+</string>
<string name="Minus">-</string>
<string name="Mal">*</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please, provide as accurate information to your question as you can, What do you have now? What have you tried? an example of what you want is always welcome.

Comment: I edited my question. I have tried the answer from luanjot, most likely wrong because it didn't work. I could unfordgenatley not understand most answers online since I'm very new to java and android.

Comment: but, please, can you provide an example of what you have, what you get and what do you expect? think of me asking you why the sky is gray today without telling you my city or the place I'm in the world at this moment, how would you figure the reason?

Comment: @RamonBoza I see your problem. I'm sorry for not being specific. I hope you can do something with the informatioin I gave you now.

Comment: @Marius I am sorry, but I don't know what did not work. I have tried it with the example you provided and I get "25000000.00".

Comment: @luanjot On what did you run it? On my Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2 it doesn't do that. Also not on the eclipse emulator of a Nexus 4 running android 4.3.

Comment: I run it in java in Eclipse. Of course... I changed the "4.0" for the double... I don't know if you did that.

Comment: I'm sorry. As I said above, I could not get you solution to work :/ Where exactly do I put it? At the end of for example
"public void ButtonClickDurch (Viewview)"? This is probably a dumb question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, for example, you want the double to be shown with two decimals, you can use:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     
System.out.println(formatter.format(4.0));
```